# SQL Server Query Execution Problem With Blank Line

Tags: sql-server

I have a Scalar Function in SQL Server. When I call my function in the top corner in my SQL Server Management Studio Query Editor it Works but when I call my function after some blank Space/Blank New Line it shows an error

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
> subquery follows =, !=, <, <=, >, >= or when the subquery is used as
> an expression.

[image: Error Show With Image]

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[FN_ChartofAccountCode] 
(
    @ParentHeadID as int    
)
RETURNS varchar (512)
AS
BEGIN
--DECLARE 
--@ParentHeadID as int  
--SET @ParentHeadID = 864

DECLARE 
@StartPosition as int,
@Length as int,
@Format as Varchar(512),
@AccountCode as VARCHAR(512),
@TempCode as int,
@EnumAccountType as smallint

SET @AccountCode=''
SET @TempCode=0
SET @EnumAccountType=0

--Get max code for selected parent
SELECT @EnumAccountType=ISNULL(TT.AccountType,0)  FROM ChartsOfAccount AS TT WHERE TT.AccountHeadID=@ParentHeadID 
IF(@EnumAccountType=1)
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM ChartsOfAccount AS TT WHERE TT.AccountType=2)
    BEGIN
        SET @TempCode = (SELECT MAX(CONVERT(INT,ISNULL(TT.AccountCode,'0'))) FROM ChartsOfAccount AS TT WHERE TT.AccountType=2)
        SET @TempCode = @TempCode + 1000000
        IF(LEN(CONVERT(VARCHAR,@TempCode))>7)
        BEGIN
            SET @AccountCode = 'Cross Code Limit'
        END
        ELSE 
        BEGIN
            SET @AccountCode =RIGHT('0000000'+ltrim(str(@TempCode)),7)
        END
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @TempCode=1000000
        SET @AccountCode = RIGHT('0000000'+ltrim(str(@TempCode)),7)
    END
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    --Segment 2,1 
    --Group    3,2
    --Sub Group 5,3
    IF(@EnumAccountType=2) --Segment
    BEGIN
        SET @StartPosition = 2
        SET @Length = 1
        SET @Format='0'
    END
    ELSE IF(@EnumAccountType=3) --Group
    BEGIN
        SET @StartPosition = 3
        SET @Length = 2
        SET @Format='00'
    END
    ELSE IF(@EnumAccountType=4)--Sub Group
    BEGIN
        SET @StartPosition = 5
        SET @Length = 3
        SET @Format='000'
    END

    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM ChartsOfAccount WHERE ParentHeadID=@ParentHeadID)
    BEGIN
        SET @TempCode = (SELECT MAX(CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(ISNULL(TT.AccountCode,'0'), @StartPosition, @Length)))+1 FROM ChartsOfAccount AS TT WHERE TT.ParentHeadID=@ParentHeadID)             
        IF(LEN(CONVERT(VARCHAR,@TempCode))>@Length)
        BEGIN
            SET @AccountCode = 'Cross Code Limit'
        END
        ELSE 
        BEGIN
            SET @AccountCode = CONVERT(VARCHAR,(SELECT MAX(CONVERT(INT, ISNULL(TT.AccountCode,'0'))) FROM ChartsOfAccount AS TT WHERE TT.ParentHeadID=@ParentHeadID))
            SET @AccountCode = STUFF(@AccountCode, @StartPosition, @Length, RIGHT(@Format+ltrim(str(@TempCode)),@Length))
        END
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @TempCode=1
        SET @AccountCode = (SELECT TT.AccountCode FROM ChartsOfAccount AS TT WHERE TT.AccountHeadID=@ParentHeadID)      
        SET @AccountCode = STUFF(@AccountCode, @StartPosition, @Length, RIGHT(@Format+ltrim(str(@TempCode)),@Length))
    END
END
--SELECT @AccountCode 
RETURN @AccountCode 
END
```

Comment: What happens if you have the extra blank lines, but then you **highlight** that line with the `SELECT`  call and execute just the selected T-SQL code?

Comment: How many rows have that parent id in ChartOfAccounts?

Comment: @shawnt00 all queries are returned single record/row I check it

Comment: Given that the other select statements against `ChartsOfAccount` are aggregating I'd be checking what this statement returns, `SELECT TT.AccountCode FROM ChartsOfAccount AS TT WHERE TT.AccountHeadID=@ParentHeadID`

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Here AccountHeadID is a primary key of ChartsOfAccount table so there is no option for return multiple data return

Comment: What is `SELECT @@VERSION`? If AccountHeadID is a primary key of ChartsOfAccount then only thought I have is that maybe scalar UDF inlining is related. (In which case probably you will be on 2019 but not the latest build)

Comment: @MartinSmith Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5 (X64)   Sep 24 2019 13:48:23   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0 <X64> (Build 17763: )

Comment: There have been a lot of bug fixes for scalar UDFs since then. Probably the extra white space means that the same cached execution plan isn't used and you get a different plan that has an issue. Get the XML for the **estimated** execution plans for both and paste them here https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan if you want some help determining the issue

Comment: Try upgrading to the latest build of SQL Server 2019, you are still on the first release and are missing many updates. Please supply a [mcve] with your table definition and some sample data for testing